# Consul KV store endpoints

Tags: consul, consul-kv

I am working on designing a little project where I need to use [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) to  manage application configuration in a dynamic way so that all my app machines can get the configuration at the same time without any inconsistency issue. We are using `Consul` already for service discovery purpose so I was reading more about it and it looks like they have a `Key/Value` store which I can use to manage my configurations.

We already have a Consul up and running and below is the url I get if I click `Key/Value` store tab:

```
http://consul.host.orcld.com/ui/#/dc1/kv/
```

I am trying to do below things with the `Consul` through command line as of now:

1. Create new key/value in Consul.
2. Update value of existing key.
3. Keep a watch on the existing key so that if value changes then I get notified and it can show me the new value of that key.

Now I already have few keys created with some values in it through ui so I was thinking to get value of that key. Below is the image but I am confuse on how can I get the value of this key in the command line:

[image]

I tried with below curl call but it doesn't give me the value of it as I get `404 Not Found`? Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
curl -XGET http://consul.host.orcld.com/vi/kv/example/reaper
```

Also how can I create new key/value and keep a watch on existing key through command line as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below format, replace `v1` instead of `vi`

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/example/reaper
```

Documentation : https://www.consul.io/api/kv.html

Comment: aah silly me. sorry about that. also can you help me with watch command? couldn't find that. I want to keep a watch on a key to figure out the changes to it if hapens.